# Uploading .pdf to quickbooks desktop

Tags: c#, pdf, quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

I was successfully able to import all the invoices,customer and bills data from my c# application into quick books by using qbxml schema and RequestProcessor2 object .

The problem I am facing here is how to upload pdf file associated with any of the invoices or bills ?

There is hardly any documentation available for doing this programmatically. One can upload the document easily to the web version of quickbooks but I am trying to upload it to the desktop version of quickbooks i.e. the .qbw file.

Answer (score 0):

As of now QBSDK doesn't support this feature. That's why you can't do this programmatically in QBD.